# Laravel does not get updates to a command. It works even if I clean the file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, caching, console

I have a command that I launch with the code:

```
php artisan reminder
```

I am trying to edit the command, but laravel does not get the updates. I literally tried to clean the file (of the command) but the command worked anyway.

I also tried with these commands, without success:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\my_proj>c:/xampp/php/php.exe artisan cache:clear
Cache cleared successfully.

C:\xampp\htdocs\my_proj>c:/xampp/php/php.exe artisan route:clear
Route cache cleared!

C:\xampp\htdocs\my_proj>c:/xampp/php/php.exe artisan config:clear
Configuration cache cleared!

C:\xampp\htdocs\my_proj>c:/xampp/php/php.exe artisan view:clear
Compiled views cleared!
```

Comment: try composer dump-autoload  and php artisan clear-compiled